# linker command failed error in case of Twitter+Oauth libraries

Tags: objective-c, xcode, twitter

```
  i am integrating twitter iOS app with my iOS app just for login purpose and for that i am using SCTwitter and Twitter+OAuth frameworks. but the problem is that when i  build my project it gave me a compiler error like below:-

    **ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/Users/harvinder/Desktop/iphone_app 13/Twitter+OAuth/Libraries'
    ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L&'
    ld: warning: directory not found for option '-LHeaders'
    ld: library not found for -lOAuth
    clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)**
```

the above error clearly stated that the Twitter+OAuth library is not found but i have recheck my project and it is added and also i have tried many things like
 1. library search paths($(PROJECT_DIR)/Twitter+OAuth/Libraries & Headers)
 2.also check Link Binary And Libraries under build phases for libxml2.dylib and libOAuth.a

```
    At last i delete the Twitter+OAuth folder and readded it and then everything works fine but the wired thing is that on the next day when i reopen my project in Xcode ,the same error encounter again  and again i delete and readded the Twitter+OAuth folder and everything works fine again and same thing happens on the next day too. so i don't understand this weird behavior. 
    so please help me on this because everyday i have to delete and readd the folder to run my project.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Spaces are used to separate command line options and the directory with the library contains spaces, so you will need to ensure the command line interpreter doesn't see those spaces.  That is generally done using quotes, so try this value in the *Library Search Paths*:

```
'$(PROJECT_DIR)/Twitter+OAuth/Libraries & Headers'
^                                                ^
```

Alternatively avoid using spaces in directory names.